# python Pandas: transform dataframe adding grouped columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have the following dataframe:

```
    n   startdate     enddate  count
0   1  2014-02-01  2014-02-01   6069
1   1  2014-02-01  2014-03-01   1837
2   1  2014-02-01  2014-04-01    107
3   1  2014-02-01  2014-05-01     54
4   1  2014-03-01  2014-03-01  10742
5   1  2014-03-01  2014-04-01   2709
6   1  2014-03-01  2014-05-01   1387
7   1  2014-04-01  2014-04-01   5584
8   1  2014-04-01  2014-05-01   1103
9   1  2014-05-01  2014-05-01   2970
```

Is it possible to transform it into something similar to:

```
    n  startdate   2014-02-01  2014-03-01 2014-04-01   2014-05-01
0   1  2014-02-01  6069        1837       107          54
1   1  2014-03-01  0           10742      2709         1387
2   1  2014-04-01  0           0          5584         1103
3   1  2014-05-01  0           0          0            2970
```

Thanks!

Comment: add how you created the dataframe. but some hints: play around with the functions `groupby`, `unstack`, and maybe `sum`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

without recreating your dataframe, i think it's going to be something like:

```
df.groupby(['n', 'startdate', 'enddate']).sum().unstack()
```

you might need to fill some nan values as well:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```